# laravel 5 validation using request not working - Undefined variable error

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-5, request

I am using Laravel 5.2, I have form and wanting to insert fields with validation. I made createQuranRequest under Requests folder and trying to echo validation errors but I get below error

> ErrorException in a19890dff92858726bf2b1048815af329d53d3b6.php line 6:
>   Undefined variable: errors (View: 
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quran/resources/views/pages/quranForm.blade.php)
>   (View:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quran/resources/views/pages
>   /quranForm.blade.php)

My quranForm.blade.php code where I am trying to spit errors

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!!Form::label('title','Surah Title:')!!}    
  {!!Form::text('title',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!} 
  <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('title') }}</span>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   {!!Form::label('lyrics','Surah Lyrics:')!!}       
   {!!Form::textarea('lyrics',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}  
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   {!!Form::submit('Add Surah',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
 </div>
```

My createQuranRequest file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class createQuranRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'lyrics' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

My controller file

```
public function store(createQuranRequest $request, quran $quran){ 
  $quran->create($request->all());
  return redirect('quran');
}
```

I have tried below code

```
@if (Session::get('errors'))
  <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{ { $error } }</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

It removed the Exception Error but does not display the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The laravel documentations says that  the $errors variable is bound to the view by the Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware, which is provided by the web middleware group.

so u have to update your routes file located in app/http/routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () 
{
    //this route will use the middleware of the 'web' group, so session and auth will work here         
    Route::post('/your-endpoint','MyController@store');       
});
```